# Problems setting up using roles in cubes (SSAS) by executing stored procedures

Tags: c#, security, tuples, ssas, mdx

I'm configuring access to a cube (SSAS) by executing a stored procedure that returns the items that each user has access. I'm doing this filter through filters data from a particular dimension, by running a method in a dll that returns an MDX expression with the particular filter for that user.

The problem I am having is that when the user has permissions to more than 50 items, only returns the first 50 returned by the stored procedure.

Has someone solved something similar and know how to fix it? Do you know if the SET class has some limited on the number of tuples returned?

This is the Method i'm using:

```
public static Set FilterUNByUserName(string UserAccount)
    {
        Expression expr = new Expression();
        SetBuilder sb = new SetBuilder();

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            // prepare connection and command
            cn.ConnectionString =
              string.Format(
                "data source={0};initial catalog={1};integrated security={2};",
                "server",
                "ddbb",
                "sspi"
            );
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandText = "[Seguridad].[FilterUNbyUser]";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserAccount", UserAccount);
            // execute stored procedure
            SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult);
            bool hasRow = r.Read();
            // iterate through the result set
            while (true == hasRow)
            {
                // add each member key to MDX set
                expr.ExpressionText = string.Format("[BI UNIT].[UN Id].&[{0}]", r[0].ToString());
                Member m = expr.CalculateMdxObject(null).ToMember();
                TupleBuilder tb = new TupleBuilder();
                tb.Add(m);
                sb.Add(tb.ToTuple());
                hasRow = r.Read();
            }
            cn.Close();
            // return MDX set
            return sb.ToSet();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you been able to attach a debugger and see whether sb contains >50 items, and indeed whether the Set has >50 items before it leaves the stored proc? That way we can find out whether it's a limitation in the SetBuilder or SSAS's Set handling through stored procs...